# A Cannondale Mountainbike for Giveaway: The Rules (Perhaps)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We've got another bike for giveaway. Here's what I'm thinking about the details + rules. Please respond with what you like and what you don't and we'll iron out the details. I'd like to get this campaign started Monday 11/21.

[image]

The Prize: [**Cannondale Trail SL 29er 3**](http://www.rei.com/product/827819/cannondale-trail-sl-29er-3-bike-2012) (or a bicycle purchased through REI for equal or lesser value - $999)

The Rules:

- Ask a question or leave an answer that earns a score of +2 to enter your name into the contest.
- Earn [**sharing badges**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) to multiply your chance of winning:

  - **x3** for Announcer (25 unique IPs in 3 days), **x10** for Booster (300 unique IPs in 4 days), **x20** for Publicist (1,000 unique IPs in 5 days)
- As unpaid members of the community, moderators are eligible.
- This contest will last 2 weeks.
- The badge must be earned by the last day of the 2 weeks for the multiplier to go into effect.
- REI will help promote the contest through its Twitter and Facebook accounts. As REI only has [stores](http://www.rei.com/stores/storeloc.html) in the US and only ships bicycles in the US, only US users will be eligible to win this contest.

Any gripes? Voice them!

Comment: NOTE: Sharing badges are rewarded in succession and cannot be earned on the same question. 15 Bikes.SE users have earned the [Announcer Badge](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer). They will not be eligible for that multiplyer duing this contest. Nobody has yet earned a Booster or Publicist badge at this site.

Comment: Also, it takes 5 days for the Publicist badge to take effect (and 4 for Booster and 3 for Announcer). For this reason, should the badge's be tallied 5 days after the final day of the contest?

Comment: Do I have to earn a sharing badge on a question/answer that I created after the competition started?

Comment: It's a shame it's another US only competition :(

Comment: @Ambo100 - The last giveaway was international. In fact, our grand prize winner lives in Germany. The next contest after this will very likely also be international. It just so happens that our main partner here is US-based and does almost exclusive US business.

Comment: @Ambo100 - The multiplier can be earned by achieving the sharing badges through any question on the bikes site.

Comment: @Ambo100 - This contest is now international (well, sorta). See here: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/571/cannondale-mountainbike-giveaway